# Application start automatically when the device is placed in the car doc if use check the checkbox

Tags: android

I want my application start automatically when the device is placed in the car doc. I find this useful code for manifest but I want to give user option with checkbox if he want to use this option.

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_DOCK" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

How to make this possible if user check option then app will be started when it is placed in the car dock, otherway not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the above manifest entries for a broadcast reciever and not for a activity. And inside broadcast receiver you can check the preference and then launch the activity.

Edit:
Register the DockReciever with above manifest changes. If that does not work then use below action

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_DOCK_EVENT"/>
```

you will have to check the state of the dock if you use this.

```
public class DockReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean launch = settings.getBoolean(Utility.KEY_LAUNCH, false);
        if(settings.getBoolean(Utility.KEY_LAUNCH, false)){
         Intent intent = //your Activity intent goes here
         arg0.startActivity(intent);
         }

     }

}
```

Comment: thank you for answer. Can I see some code exaple somewhere maybe?